# Issues with modifying a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector, openframeworks

I am having some memory problems while trying to update some objects.

First I call setup(), which is working just fine, but when I call update(), I get bad access errors, which I have a feeling might be an issue with something I have already read: I am modifying a copy, not the actual pointer. I have explored using double pointers for that function, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around it. Does anyone have some advice?

```
class ofxGrowth {
     ofxGrowthNode * root;
     vector<unique_ptr<ofMesh>> meshes;

     void setup();
     void setupMesh(ofxGrowthNode * temp_node, ofMesh * temp_mesh, int mesh_node_id, bool share_root);
     void update();
     void updateMesh(ofxGrowthNode * temp_node, ofMesh * temp_mesh, int mesh_node_id, int current_mesh);

     ofxGrowth();
    ~ofxGrowth();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
//setup creates the mesh system, which is working properly
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofxGrowth::setup(){
    root = new ofxGrowthNode(*this);
    num_nodes = 0;

    unique_ptr<ofMesh> mesh = make_unique<ofMesh>();
    mesh->setMode(OF_PRIMITIVE_LINE_STRIP);

    meshes.push_back(std::move(mesh));

    setupMesh(root, meshes.back().get(),0,false);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofxGrowth::setupMesh(ofxGrowthNode * temp_node, ofMesh * temp_mesh, int mesh_node_id, bool share_root){
    temp_mesh->addVertex(temp_node->location);
    temp_mesh->addIndex(mesh_node_id);
    temp_mesh->addColor(ofFloatColor(1,0,0));

    for(int i = 0; i < temp_node->children.size(); i++){
        if(i > 0){
            unique_ptr<ofMesh> new_mesh = make_unique<ofMesh>();
            new_mesh->setMode(OF_PRIMITIVE_LINE_STRIP);
            new_mesh->addVertex(temp_node->location);
            new_mesh->addIndex(0);

            new_mesh->addColor(ofFloatColor(0,1,0));

            temp_mesh = new_mesh.get();
            meshes.push_back(move(new_mesh));
            mesh_node_id = 0;
        }

        mesh_node_id++;

        temp_node = temp_node->children[i].get();
        setupMesh(temp_node, temp_mesh, mesh_node_id, share_root);
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
//update is meant to re-traverse the meshes, updating the
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofxGrowth::update(){
    updateMesh(root, meshes[0].get(),0,0);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofxGrowth::updateMesh(ofxGrowthNode * temp_node, ofMesh * temp_mesh, int mesh_node_id, int current_mesh){
    temp_mesh->setVertex(mesh_node_id, temp_node->location);
    temp_mesh->setColor(mesh_node_id, ofFloatColor(1,0,0));

    for(int i = 0; i < temp_node->children.size(); i++){
        if(i > 0){
            temp_mesh = meshes[current_mesh + 1].get();

            current_mesh = current_mesh + 1;
            mesh_node_id = 0;
        }

        mesh_node_id++;

        temp_node = temp_node->children[i].get();
        updateMesh(temp_node, temp_mesh, mesh_node_id, current_mesh);
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that a call to get function does not make unique_ptr release ownership of the pointer (i.e., it is still responsible for deleting the managed data at some point). Therefore, the value returned by this function shall not be used to construct a new managed pointer.

In order to obtain the stored pointer and release ownership over it, call unique_ptr::release instead. Use temp_mesh = new_mesh.release();

Comment: Thanks @user1438832 I think this actually might solve another issue I had. So when I have a unique_ptr that needs to be overwritten regularly, it is better to release it when it's moved to a more permanent location? When exactly do I release the pointer?

Comment: After calling release  the unique_ptr object is released from the responsibility of deleting the object. Some other entity must take responsibility for deleting the object at some point.In your case when you want to clear or delete the elements in meshes you should explicitly call delete.

Comment: It will be better to define meshes as vector of unique_ptr then you dont have to call delete explicitly.

Comment: Just updated the code above to include a constructor with a vector of unique_ptr. Is this proper?

Comment: create meshes as member of ofxGrowth class.You are defininf meshes in the constructor which goes out of scope when constructor return,dont do it.

Comment: Sorry if i am confusing you.But it seems to ok now.

Comment: No problem at all, and I understand what you are saying, that in particular is in part because of eliminating too much code for the question, something I'm still not great at doing but trying to get better with it (and obviously, it would have been good for me to include these things). meshes is a vector<unique_ptr<ofMesh>>, and currently works